# Refresh single div and contents inside

Tags: javascript, reload

I'm trying to refresh the datepicker `<div>` and also reload/recall the javascript in Calendar.js when `refreshCalendar()` is called.

My code for the `<div>`:

```
<div class="starlet calendar">
  <header>
    <h2>My Calendar</h2>
      <div onclick="refreshCalendar();" class="action ss-sync"></div>
  </header>
  <div class="datepicker bfh-datepicker" data-format="y-m-d" data-date="today"></div>
  <div class="weather"></div>
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    <%@ include file="js/Calendar.js" %>
</script>
```

Can anyone assist. What is the easiest method of doing this.

Comment: You can either use Ajax to replace the contents, or you can replace the contents with another hidden div in the same page

Comment: Something like function refreshCalendarAndStuff() { refreshCalendar(); doStuff(); }
?

Comment: I'm having trouble with what to put inside of those functions

Comment: Can you provide a link to the plugin you're using..?